# How can I pass void pointer to function in C?

Tags: c, void-pointers

I have got sort function. I am passing arguments to this function like this for example:

```
double tab[] = {-46, -81, 89, -13, -24, -65, 78, -32, -92, -43, 58, -48, 87, 31, 81};
int res = sort(tab, 15, sizeof(double), comp_double);
```

Then in sort function i want to pass two elements from my tab to compare function. But there is error that pointer of type (void *) used in arithmetic.

```
typedef int(*f)(const void*, const void*);
int sort(void *ptr, int N, int sizeof_element, f f);
```

I am writing about this line which is inside sort function:

```
comp_double((void *)(ptr + j), (void *)(ptr + j + 1))
```

And my question is how to pass comp_double function concrete numbers from tab.
I can't change declarations of my functions.

EDIT:
So my comp_double function is good. And as I said, i can't change declarations of my functions. I have to sort array using sort function, so I have to use my comp fucntion. But I don't know how to pass arguments to it.

```
int comp_double(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2){
    if(ptr1 == NULL || ptr2 == NULL){
        return 100;
    }
    if(*(double *)ptr1 > *(double *)ptr2){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(*(double *)ptr1 < *(double *)ptr2){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int sort(void *ptr, int N, int sizeof_element, f function){
    if(ptr == NULL || N <= 0 || sizeof_element <= 0 || function == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    if(function == comp_double){
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < N - 1; j++){
                if(comp_double((void *)(ptr + j), (void *)(ptr + j + 1)) == 1){
                    double temp = 0;
                    temp = *(double *)(ptr + j);
                    *(double *)(ptr + j) = *(double *)(ptr + j + 1);
                    *(double *)(ptr + j + 1) = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my error:

```
comparators.c: In function ‘sort’:
comparators.c:12:45: error: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Werror=pointer-arith]
                 if(comp_double((void *)(ptr + j), (void *)(ptr + j + 1)) == 1)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Instead of showing crippled fractions of your code, please show at least whole functions.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: You don't need to cast a pointer to `void*`. But you must cast a `void*` to another pointer type before doing pointer arithmetics. For a sort function, `uint8_t*` comes to my mind. Then you must apply the `sizeof_element` parameter accordingly.

Comment: You might look up bubble sort algorithm. You could at least cut the runtime in half. After the inner loop has completed, one element (first or last) is supposed to be in place. There is no need to check again in each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: may I ask what is the purpose of this "generic" C programming mambo-jambo, while you have a direct cast to `double*` in your sorting code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I pass void pointer to function in C?

You already are, so that's not your problem.

> I am writing about this line which is inside sort function:

> ```
> comp_double((void *)(ptr + j), (void *)(ptr + j + 1))
> ```

OK, it's not passing `void*` you're having trouble with, but doing pointer arithmetic on it.

The reason is that there's no type associated with `void*`, so the compiler doesn't know how many bytes `ptr+1` should be advanced. If you were using `char *ptr`, it would be one byte. For `double* ptr` it would be `sizeof(double)` bytes, etc.

Since we can't cast `ptr` to the correct type (it can be different on each call, which is what makes the function reusable), we have to do this pointer arithmetic manually instead:

```
char *base = (char *)ptr;
...
comp_double(base + j*sizeof_element, base + (j + 1)*sizeof_element);
```

Notes:

1. the pointer argument can be implicitly cast back to `void*`, there's no need to do it explicitly
2. any pointer `T*` such that `sizeof(T)==1` will work correctly: `char` is kind of traditional, `uint8` is also fine

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you did not provide enough code to show it in your code.
You will need to fill the blanks.

To call the passed compare function, you need to do the arithmetics on your own:

```c
int sort(void *ptr, int N, int sizeof_element, f f)
{
  uint8*p = ptr;
  // ... Doing the sorting things...
  //Assuming you want to compare element j and k in the array
  int result = f( &p[j*sizeof_element], &p[k*sizeof_element] );
  // ... Doing more sorting things
}
```

With your updated code I want to add, that you mustn't call `comp_double` directly in the `sort` function. That is what `f` is intented to be used for.

The error message you get is because you cannot do pointer arithmetics on a `void*` as `void` does not have a size. (Except with some GCC extensions)

Comment: thanks you for your answer, I have edited my post and I pasted more code